# Permutation in discrete math

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations

Is the permutation 
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1& 2 &3 &4 &5 &6&7 \\ 7 & 4 & 2 & 1 & 3 & 6 & 5 \end{pmatrix}$$
even or odd?

The product of disjoint cycles is $$\begin{pmatrix}1& 7&5&3&2&4\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}6\end{pmatrix}$$

and the transposition are $$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 7 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 5 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 4 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}6 \end{pmatrix}$$ is it correct?

and the answer is even??

I feel confused about this..

Comment: (6) is not a transposition, look at my answer below.

Comment: ok i get it..thanks ya@OfirSchnabel

Comment: $(6)$ is not a transposition. A transposition is the swapping of two elements (a permutation of order $2$). Drop that off and you have five transpositions -- so it is odd. There are many correct ways to write a permutation as a product of transpositions; your way is one such correct product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is as you said $$(1,7,5,3,2,4),$$
and then it is equal to 
$$(1,7)(7,5)(5,3)(3,2)(2,4),$$
and hence it is odd.

Comment: It should be $(3,2)$ and not $(5,2)$. Just a small error.

Comment: Thanks, wasnt careful enough

Answer (score 1):

You only need the decomposition in disjoint cycles. Since $\;(1\;7\;5\;3\;2\;4)\;$ as even length, it is an **odd** cycle and thus is your original permutation

Answer (score 0):

Another way to check the parity of a permutation is to see how many pairs are out of order (this is the number of [inversions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_%28discrete_mathematics%29)). There are $11$:
$$
\{(7,4),(7,2),(7,1),(7,3),(7,6),(7,5),(4,2),(4,1),(4,3),(2,1),(6,5)\}
$$
Thus, this is an odd permutation.